# Help in understanding what is going on in $A[G]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, group-rings

Ok, so Im given a group $G$ and a ring $A$, and define:

$$A[G]=\left\{\sum_{g \in G} f(g)  g : f:G \to A, \text{ such that $f$ has finite support}  \right\}$$

Define the sum $(+)$:

$$\sum_{g \in G} f(g)  g + \sum_{g \in G} h(g)  g = \sum_{g \in G} (f(g)+h(g))  g$$

And multiplication $(\cdot)$:

$$\sum_{\alpha \in G} f(\alpha)  \alpha \cdot \sum_{\beta \in G} h(\beta)  \beta = \sum_{g\in G}\left(\sum_{\alpha \beta = g} f(\alpha)h(\beta)\right)  g$$

And then $(A, +, \cdot)$ is a ring.

Now, Im trying to calculate $Z(A[G])$, and Ive got a suggestion that says to first show that if $\sum_{g \in G} f(g)  g \in Z(A[G])$ then $f(g) \in Z(A)$ for every $g\in G$.

So I take  $\sum_{g \in G} f(g)  g \in Z(A[G])$ and then for any  $\sum_{g \in G} h(g)  g \in A[G]$, we have that

$$\sum_{\alpha \in G} f(\alpha)  \alpha \cdot \sum_{\beta \in G} h(\beta)  \beta =\sum_{\beta \in G} h(\beta)  \beta \cdot \sum_{\alpha \in G} f(\alpha)  \alpha$$

So I thought, ok, given $x\in A$ lets take $h:G \to A$ given by $h(1_{G})=x$ and $h(g)=0$ for every $g \in G-\{1\}$, in order to show that $f(g) \in Z(A)$ for every $g \in G$. So here comes my misunderstanding: For this given $h$,

$$\sum_{\alpha \in G} f(\alpha)  \alpha \cdot \sum_{\beta \in G} h(\beta)  \beta = \sum_{\alpha \in G} f(\alpha)  \alpha \cdot (x \cdot 1_{G} + \sum_{g \in G-\{1\}} 0 \cdot g)$$

But $0 \in A$ and $g \in G$ and (I've have not studied Modules until now) and therefore, In principle I don't know how to multiply $0 \cdot g$. In fact I don't know how to multiply any $a \in A$ times any $g\in G$. So what's the issue? I don't need that? Where am I lost?

Comment: You didn't say so, but I assume $f\colon G \to A$?

Comment: Also, are you assuming that both $G$ and $A$ are commutative? If not, then $A[G]$ isn't commutative. For example, assume $G$ isn't abelian. Then consider $\alpha, \beta \in G$ such that $\alpha\beta = \theta \neq \tau = \beta \alpha$, the function $f(\alpha) = a$, $f(g) = 0$ for every $g \neq \alpha$, and the function $h(\beta) = b$, $h(g) = 0$ for every $g \neq \beta$. So $\sum_{g \in G} f(g)g = a \alpha$ and $\sum_{g \in G} h(g)g = b \beta$, thus $$(a\alpha) \cdot (b\beta) = (ab) \theta$$ but $$(b\beta) \cdot (a\alpha) = (ba) \tau.$$

Comment: Im not assuming neither $G$ nor $A$ is commutative, and in fact, In fact, im trying to calculate $Z(A[G])$ which would be trivial if $A[G]$ were commutative.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I didn't catch the $\sum_{g\in G} f(g)g \in Z(A[G])$ bit.

Comment: You don't have to multiply $0$ and $g$. In the original definition you have terms $f(g)g$ with $f(g) \in A$ and $g \in G$, and $0g$ is just an instance of this with $f(g)=0$. The terms $f(g)g$ are not products, they are just pairs of elements, one from $A$ and one from $G$. It might have been clearer to write them as $(f(g),g)$ but the notation $f(g)g$ is standard.

Comment: Well, in that case, what should I think about when trying to find a function $h:G \to A$ with finite support as to show that if $\sum_{g \in G} f(g) g \in Z(A[G])$ then $f(g) \in Z(A)$ for every $g \in G$?

Comment: You were on the right track. Choose $h$ as you suggested. The fact that $h$ commutes with $\sum f(g)g$ implies that $x$ commutes with $f(g)$ for all $g \in G$. This is true for all $x$, so $f(g) \in Z(A)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the $g$ in $\sum_{g \in G} f(g) g$ as placeholders, the same way as the $x^j$ act as placeholders in a polynomial's expression $a_nx^n + \dotsb + a_1x^1 + a_0x^0$. This should make it easier to see that $$\sum_{g \in G} f(g) g = \sum_{g \in G} h(g) g$$ if and only if $$f(g) = h(g)\quad \text{for every } g \in G.$$
Using your choice of $h$, for any given $x \in A$ you get
$$
\sum_{\alpha \in G} f(\alpha)\alpha \cdot \sum_{\beta \in G} h(\beta)\beta
= \sum_{\alpha \in G} \big(f(\alpha)x\big) \alpha
= \sum_{\alpha \in G} \big(xf(\alpha)\big) \alpha
= \sum_{\beta \in G} h(\beta)\beta \cdot \sum_{\alpha \in G} f(\alpha)\alpha
$$
which by the remark above means that $f(g)x = xf(g)$ for every $g \in G$.

---

Following the OP's comment below, let's look a bit more in detail at how one can compute those products. By definition
$$
\sum_{\alpha \in G} f(\alpha)\alpha \cdot \sum_{\beta \in G} h(\beta)\beta
= \sum_{g \in G} \left(\sum_{\alpha\beta=g} f(\alpha) h(\beta)\right) g
$$
so let's compute the sum in brackets for a given $g \in G$. Now, consider some $\alpha,\beta \in G$ such that $\alpha\beta = g$, and suppose that $\beta \neq 1_G$. Then by your choice of $h$ we have $h(\beta) = 0$, thus $f(\alpha) h(\beta) = 0$. Since the sum in brackets is computed in $A$, it follows that
$$
\sum_{\alpha\beta=g} f(\alpha) h(\beta) = f(g)h(1_G) + \sum_{\substack{\alpha\beta=g\\\beta\neq1_G}} 0 = f(g)x.
$$
Similarly for the other product.

---

On the other hand, note that when you have some concrete elements of $A[G]$ you can compute products in a simpler way. Indeed, for ease of notation let's agree that, when writing out an element of $A[G]$, we will omit all terms with coefficient $0$. Then the finiteness condition means that every non-zero element of $A[G]$ is of the form $a_1 g_1 + \dotsb + a_n g_n$ for some $g_1,\dotsc,g_n \in G$ and $a_1,\dotsc,a_n \in A$ non-zero. Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
(a_1g_1+\dotsb+a_ng_n)(b_1h_1+\dotsb+b_mh_m) &= (a_1b_1)(g_1h_1) + \dotsb + (a_1b_m)(g_1h_m)\\&+(a_2b_1)(g_2h_1) + \dotsb + (a_nb_m)(g_nh_m).
\end{align}
$$
If this looks a lot like a product of polynomials, you are not mistaken. The same definitions for sum and product in $A[G]$ still work when $G$ is a monoid instead of a group, and if you take $G = \{X^n : n \in \Bbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\}$ you recover the ring of polynomials $A[X]$.

With this in mind, let's revisit the previous product:
$$
\sum_{\alpha \in G} f(\alpha)\alpha \cdot \sum_{\beta \in G} h(\beta)\beta
= \left(\sum_{\alpha \in G} f(\alpha)\alpha\right) (x1_G)
= \sum_{\alpha \in G} (f(\alpha)x)(\alpha1_G)
= \sum_{\alpha \in G} (f(\alpha)x)\alpha.
$$

Comment: I expanded my answer. I hope this will be enough to clear your doubts.